# How do I install and use nlatexdb? (or latexdb, ratexdb)?

Tags: xetex, database

This question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/how-can-i-typeset-with-latexdb-using-xelatex) regarding typesetting a MySQL database using UTF-8 encoding with Xelatex.

I ask this in desperation as it involved printing 552 rows for my thesis! I need to get this information to my adviser this week and he is a bit old-fashion (meaning he would rather have everything on paper, not on a computer and certainly not in computer code).

System Details:

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
- Tex Live 2012 installed with Macports
- MySQL 5.5 Server (installed via DMG)

How can I get any of the three latexdb systems installed? (the related question above involved making it work with xelatex).

Server is running fine. I can log in and make queries.

I have a simple document:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\texdbconnection{MySQL,localhost,root,password,mydatabase}
\texdbdef{##query1}{select hd,md from mytable}{##hd,##md}

\begin{document}
This is a header for the page.

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Hochdeutsch & Mantakisch \\
\texdbfor{##query1}{\hline \textit{##hd} & \textbf{##md}\\}
\hline
\end{tabular}\\

\end{document}
```

I keep getting errors like:

> latexdb database.tex Pre-Compiling database.tex (loop 1) This is
>   XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/MacPorts 2012_7) 
>   restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./database.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel  and hyphenation patterns for
>   english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo aded.
>   (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (./database.aux))
>   *

Or it just hangs like this:

```
latexdb database.tex
Pre-Compiling database.tex (loop 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/latexdb.py", line 274, in <module>
    _main_()
  File "/opt/local/bin/latexdb.py", line 262, in _main_
    texDBparseForLoop(l)
  File "/opt/local/bin/latexdb.py", line 151, in texDBparseForLoop
    for qR in texDBresult(queryString):
  File "/opt/local/bin/latexdb.py", line 68, in texDBresult
    cursor=db.cursor()
NameError: global name 'db' is not defined
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/MacPorts 2012_7)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./database.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
) (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4].

(./database.aux) (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd))

*
```

It seems like I am really close to getting this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nlatexdb doesn't need to be installed. You just need the file nlatexdb.exe. You can copy it anywhere, e.g. into the same folder as xelatex.

For MySql and Mono, you will have to perform some more steps, as explained on this page:
http://sourceforge.net/p/nlatexdb/wiki/MySQL%20and%20Mono/

Also, if the tex files are in UTF-8, you'll have to add the command line parameter "-e utf-8".